# card rendering function fails only after clicking on pagination button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why my function that renders bootstrap 5 cards fails but only after first clicking a pagination button then selecting a drop down menu option. The pagination buttons work fine it seems and the dropdown menu also works fine but only if a pagination button is never clicked.

The problem seems to be in my `displayList()` function. After clicking a pagination button and clicking a dropdown option the correct array is passed into `displayList()` but `let paginatedItems = items.slice(start, end);` returns an empty array. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

I've my stripped down code so that hopefully it's easier to read and understand:

```js
const setPosters = [{id:'1',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Virus Treatments',author:'Sam Smith',category:'treatments'},{id:'2',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Treatments',author:'Dave Smith',category:'illness'},{id:'3',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Pain',author:'Sam Smith',category:'illness'},{id:'4',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Virus Treatments',author:'Bob Burke',category:'illness'},{id:'5',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Pain Treatments',author:'James Frank',category:'cures'},{id:'6',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Sinus Treatments',author:'Ted Reed',category:'illness'},{id:'7',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Migrain Treatments',author:'Ted Reed',category:'remedy'},{id:'8',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Flu Treatments',author:'Ted Reed',category:'remedy'},{id:'9',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Virus Treatments',author:'James Frank',category:'remedy'},{id:'10',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Flu Treatments',author:'Ralph Barnes ',category:'remedy'},{id:'11',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Virus Treatments',author:'Thomas Smith',category:'cures'},{id:'12',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Pain Treatments',author:'Ralph Barnes',category:'remedy'},{id:'13',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Virus Treatments',author:'Sam Smith',category:'treatments'},{id:'14',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Treatments',author:'Dave Smith',category:'illness'},{id:'15',img:'libs/images/pdfFile.jpg',title:'Pain',author:'Sam Smith',category:'illness'},]
// this continues for a total of about 80 cards in my local version

let posters;
const cardElement = $('#cards');
const paginationElement = $('#pagination');

let currentPage = 1;
let rows = 10;
let page_count;

///////////\\\\\\\\\\\
// **** Functions ***\\
//////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
function displayList(items, wrapper, rows_per_page, page) {
  wrapper.html("");
  page--;
  console.log('displayList', items);
  let start = rows_per_page * page;
  let end = start + rows_per_page;
  let paginatedItems = items.slice(start, end);
  console.log('paginatedItems:', paginatedItems);
  for (let i = 0; i < paginatedItems.length; i++) {
    wrapper.append(`
      <div class="col gx-2">
          <div class="card">
          <img
              src=${paginatedItems[i].img}
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="..."
          />
              <div class="card-body p-1">

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  Title: ${paginatedItems[i].title}
                  Category: <strong>${paginatedItems[i].category}</strong><br>
                  Author: ${paginatedItems[i].author}<br>
                  id: ${paginatedItems[i].id}<br>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>    
    `)
  };
};

function setupPagination(items, wrapper, rows_per_page) {
  wrapper.html("");
  page_count = Math.ceil(items.length / rows_per_page) + 1;

  for (let i = 1; i < page_count; i++) {
    wrapper.append(`<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">${i}</a></li>`);
  };
};

/////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
// **** Posters By Category Dropdown ***\\
////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

//Adds Categories to Dropdown Select Options
uniqCatergoriesArray = uniqCatergories(setPosters, it => it.category);

function uniqCatergories(data, key) {
  return [...new Map(data.map(x => [key(x), x])).values()]
}

for (var i = 0; i < uniqCatergoriesArray.length; i++) {
  $('#selPosterCat').append($('<option>', {
    value: uniqCatergoriesArray[i].category,
    text: uniqCatergoriesArray[i].category,
  }));
}

//Displays Posters By Category
$('#selPosterCat').on('change', function() {
  console.log($('#selPosterCat').val());
  $('#textSearchResult').html('&nbsp');
  $('#inlineFormInput').val('');

  if ($('#selPosterCat').val() === 'all') {
    posters = setPosters.filter(item => item);
    displayList(posters, cardElement, rows, currentPage);
    setupPagination(posters, paginationElement, rows);
  } else {
    posters = setPosters.filter(item => item.category === $('#selPosterCat').val());
    console.log('dropdown', posters);
    displayList(posters, cardElement, rows, currentPage);
    setupPagination(posters, paginationElement, rows);
  }
});

/////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\
// **** Pagination Click ***\\
/////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
$(document).on("click", "ul.pagination li a:not(.static)", function(e) {
  currentPage = parseInt($(this).text());
  posters = setPosters.filter(item => item);
  displayList(posters, cardElement, rows, currentPage);
});

posters = setPosters.filter(item => item)
displayList(posters, cardElement, rows, currentPage);
setupPagination(posters, paginationElement, rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- *** Main Content Container *** -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContainer">
  <div id="mainCardContainer">
    <!-- *** Search Bar *** -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <form id="form-id">
            <div class="mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 5vh;">
              <select id="selPosterCat" class="form-select-sm w-25" aria-label="Default select example" style="border-right: none; border-width: 1px; height: 2rem;">
                <option value="all" selected>All Categories</option>
                <!-- other options added here by javaScript -->
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-5 row-cols-sm-2 g-4" id="cards">
        <!-- individual cards added here by javaScript -->
      </div>

      <!-- *** Pagination Bar *** -->
      <div class="container-fluid mt-3 pe-0 me-0">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            <li class="page-item" id="previousBtn">
              <a class="page-link static" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" id="">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <div class="d-flex" id="pagination">
              <!-- page numbers added here by javaScript -->
            </div>
            <li class="page-item" id="nextBtn">
              <a class="page-link static" id="" href="#">Next</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change this code:

```
item => item.category === $('#selPosterCat').val()
```

With this:

```
item => item.category = $('#selPosterCat').val()
```

and be sure from adding these links respectively:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rewan_95/107zxr3g is the fiddle I tested on.

Note: don't forget to add the above links for testing on jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I still have the same problem in the jfiddle. If you click a category, then click around on the page numbers, then try the dropdown menu options again, no cards are displayed for a category.

Comment: I tried many times and didn't get any problem, can you add an image for that?

Comment: Yeah it's very strange. But I can recreate the problem by clicking run, then scroll down and click "2", the go to the dropdown and click, "treatments". Console logs "paginatedItems:", []" and no cards display

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my drop down select function I need to pass 1 as the currentPage to reset it, if not I pass the wrong page number.  Thank you very very much for your help and time.

Comment: I don't think so, I have just updated the answer, check it please :)

Comment: So I tried that but that actually changes the category value for every item in the array to whichever option I choose. This line `posters = setPosters.filter(item => item.category === $('#selPosterCat').val());` creates a new array with only the objects in which the category value matches the dropdown select option value.  If changed it to equals then I'll be setting each category value. Have you tried changing `currentPage` to 1 on line 88 of the jFiddle. It's easier to see when a lot more items are  copy pasted into the array. Setting it to 1 also seems to work in my other functions.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help, I  sincerely appreciate it. Discussing this with you has helped immensely.